# Sometimes the winterbash snowflake is in the wrong place

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, winter-bash-2014

My top bar is a little crowded, and sometimes the winterbash snowflake gets pushed off the end:

[image: I can has waffles? Maybe?]

Comment: You could give up your diamond....

Comment: Diamond or hats? Don't make me choose.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is pretty much a moderator only problem... lack of space on the topbar.

So, this is the compromise - push it off, as there isn't enough space for it in the middle.